# Comparing strings with C

Tags: c, string, compare

I am trying to make a basic text game in C. I am trying to compare a set string with user input but am failing miserably at it. I am rather new to C (I have worked with javascript, php, and C++ in the past). I am sure what I am doing wrong is either blindly simple or is something that I misunderstood when reading documentation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
/* Game variables */
bool game_over = false,
    is_mage = false,
    is_warrior = false;
unsigned int sword_damage = 15,
    magic_damage = 10,
    magika = 20,
    strength = 20,
    health = 100,
    gold = 20;
char name [20],
    type [7],
    dest_1 [7],
    dest_2 [7],
    mage [4],
    warrior[7];

/* Make string variables */
memset(dest_1, '\0', sizeof(dest_1));
memset(dest_2, '\0', sizeof(dest_2));
strcpy(mage, "mage");
strcpy(dest_1, mage);
strcpy(warrior, "warrior");
strcpy(dest_2, warrior);

/* Print introduction and set up player */
printf("\t\t\t\tAngrokk\n\t\tCopyright: Benjamin Williams 2013\n\n");
printf("Character name: ");
scanf("%s",name);
printf("\nCharacter type (mage/warrior): ");
scanf("%s",type);
if (strcmp(type, dest_1) == 0) {
    is_mage = true;
} else if (strcmp(type, dest_2) == 0) {
    is_warrior = true;
} else {
    printf("No type available, game shutting down.");
    return 0;
}

/* Main game loop */
while (!game_over) {

    /* Detect if the character is dead or not */
    if (health < 0) {
        game_over = true;
    }
}
printf("Game over");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!game_over)` please.

Comment: be careful with string lengths should always contain space for the '\0' character. for example your mage is only [4] long..

Comment: How many characters does it take to store "warrior". Hint: it is *more* than 7. From what I see those should all be `const char varname[] = "string value";` anyway, and you can then toss out the `strcpy()`'s.

Comment: So i should up both lengths by two. Making mage 6 and warrior 9?

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thank you very much for the help everyone. Now I can continue learning more bits and pieces of C.

Comment: One more thing... how would I convert the characters to a string.

Comment: An array of null terminated chars is a string. In your code, all of your char variables are strings.

Comment: I wish to be able to print the stored name (which as of now just prints numbers). I cannot figure out how to convert that to letters.

Comment: You may have reasons for choosing to do this in C, but in the case that you're just starting out as a programmer, I would consider doing this in a language that has a more comprehensive string manipulation features. For a text-based game, you might have an easier time with a language that has a native concept of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it through the debugger and your string comparisons are working out fine.

To define a string you can do the following (remember a string is just a pointer to the first character):

char *warrior = "warrior";

char *mage = "mage";

Then...

`if ( strcmp( mage, type ) == 0 ){

//do what you have to do

}

else if ( strcmp (warrior , type ) == 0){

//do what you have to do

}`